# Is there a Drupal 7 Module that can bypass the "preview" screen before submitting an entities webform?

Tags: php, drupal, preview, entities, drupal-webform

When the User hits submit have that form immediately display the output screen. Not sure if this even possible but I cant seem to find a module that could do this. Maybe there is a possible _hook that can achieve this also? any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: "preview" means that it will be not "live" until user will click "submit" again? By webform you mean module "Webform"? If yes -s which version you use?

Comment: yes that is correct the user fills out the form and hits submit, after that it takes them to a screen to "preview" all the info that they typed it...and then hitting submit again if the info is correct. I would just like to bypass the entire preview section. So the user only has to hit submit once for the from to go through! we are using the newest version of https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform

Comment: Oh, that's sad, Webform 4.x has this feature out of the box.

Comment: ah gotcha, unfortunately our company is using entity webforms, do you believe that this is not possible unless we use Webform 4.x?